# JavaScript confirm action using document.write

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have a JavaScript function that I am trying to call when the confirm is true. I am using `document.write` because the source document is a .js file, not html.

Before the true condition is executing, I want a confirmation from the user that they are sure they want to reset the counter.

I have two attempts - the first of which is returning true of false, but not calling the `resetCookie()` function on the true condition.

The second attempt is, I think, syntactically incorrect, as it appears to do nothing.

First attempt:

```
document.write('<a href="" onclick="return alert(confirm(\'sure?\'));{resetCookie()}{};"><i>Reset counter</i></a>');
```

Second attempt:

```
document.write("<a href='javascript: if (confirm('Continue?')) { alert('You chose true') } else { alert('You chose false.') }; void('')'>Reset counter</a>");
```

Comment: I did not got your point. What is your problem, your want to know how is best way or any of your attempts doesn't works.. ??

Comment: You can't use `document.write()` in a page once the page is completed; it will implicitly destroy the page if you do.

Comment: @Pointy: It doesn't matter whether the code is in a `.js` file or an inline `script`. All that counts is whether the `document.write` is done *during* page parsing rather than after.

Comment: Yes, of course; sorry to have been unclear. (I think that's what I meant by "in a page"; I hadn't had any coffee yet when typing that comment.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you just use the jscript confirm() function?

```
if (confirm("sure?") == true){
   resetCookie();
}
```

btw, your A tag is wrong (I'll ignore for now that you can't use document.write when already running):

```
document.write('<a href="" onclick="if(confirm(\'sure?\')){resetCookie()};return false;"><i>Reset counter</i></a>');
```

Comment: what is that going to achieve? there's an empty href property on that a tag, so it's not going anywhere (except reloading the page)...

Comment: @Leon: +1 Nice job solving the problem. Note: Just because the code is in a `.js` file, that doesn't mean it's happening after the initial page load. You can use `document.write` in an external `.js` file just like you can with inline `script`, as long as you're doing it immediately.

Comment: glad I could help! pls mark as answer for the others... Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should pay attention to your quote style - if you open a sinle quote `'` you can't use it again without escaping, try this:

```
document.write("<a href='javascript:(confirm(\"continue?\") ? alert(\"true\") : alert(\"false\"))'>Reset counter</a>");
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're including this JavaScript file inline, and assuming this code runs immediately (e.g., it's not in a function call triggered after the page loads), you can use `document.write` just fine although in general I'd avoid it.

I'd also avoid putting any kind of logic in a DOM0 (`onclick`-style) handler; instead, call a function:

```
document.write('<a href="" onclick="return confirmLink();"><i>Reset counter</i></a>');
function confirmLinkClick() {
    if (confirm("sure?")) {
        resetCookie();
    }
    return false;
}
```

Ideally, avoid DOM0 handlers entirely and use modern methods of hooking up the click, since with modern methods you can avoid creating global functions. That means using `addEventListener` (on modern browsers) or `attachEvent` (on IE8 and earlier), or better yet using a good library to avoid having to worry about those differences.

Comment: TJ, I like your thinking.  I needed to read it a couple times to really get the gist of what you are suggesting.  Thanks